# How to set Initial Catalog in connection string for Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, connection-string, identityserver3

I'm trying to setup [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to work with Oracle database. I've got working MSSQL solution and I need Oracle variation too.

During initialization I get following error. It looks like provider reaches timeout (30-45 s) and then throws the exception.

```
The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.
```

Error occurs in `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create`. To be more specific in

```
IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.DbModelBuilderExtensions
.RegisterScopeChildTablesForDelete[TScope](DbContext ctx) in
IdentityServer3.EntityFramework\Source\Core.EntityFramework\Extensions
\DbModelBuilderExtensions.cs
```

Here is my `web.config` connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationDbContext" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=xxxxxxx;
                       Password=xxxxxxx;
                       Data Source=OracleDataSource" />
```

and here is the rest of `web.config` (any how related to Oracle)

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="OracleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

How can I add `Initial Catalog` to my connection string for Oracle?

**Versions**

- IdentityServer3: v 2.5
- EntityFramework: 6.1.3
- Oracle ManagedDataAccess EntityFramework: 12.1.4

**Update 1:**

I've tried simply adding `Initial Catalog` to my conn string, but it doesn't seem to work ([Oracle XE, C++ ADO](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/oracle-xe-c-ado/)):

```
<add name="ApplicationDbContext" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=xxxxxxx;
                       Password=xxxxxxx;
                       Data Source=OracleDataSource;
                       Initial catalog=XE" />
```

Maybe `XE` is not the name of my database? Should I use `schema` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `defaultConnectionFactory`

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

After replacing with `OracleConnectionFactory` things moved on

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" />
```